# Maven/Tycho build not working on Xtext DSL when referencing existing Ecore Model

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext, eclipse-emf

I have a Xtext based DSL project , which is referring to the Ecore model defined in another project. While everything works fine within eclipse but somehow maven build fails to run.

Command -
mvn clean install

Error -

0    ERROR Mwe2Launcher       - [XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:13 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'ExpressionGeneratorModule'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:14 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'project'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:31 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'code'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:32 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'encoding'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:33 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'lineDelimiter'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:34 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'fileHeader'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:35 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'preferXtendStubs'.]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:13 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'ExpressionGeneratorModule'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:14 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'project'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:31 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'code'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:32 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'encoding'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:33 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'lineDelimiter'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:34 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'fileHeader'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:35 Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'preferXtendStubs'.]

Implementation Details -

1. Xtext version - 2.22.0
2. Maven/tycho based eclipse-plugin.
3. org.eclipse.xtext.generator  bundle added in manifest.
4. referencedResource =
   "platform:/resource/com.act21.mamba.model/model/expression.genmodel"
   present in workflow.
5. import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.* , present
   in workflow.

Grammar Snippet-

```
grammar com.act21.mamba.expression.dsl.ExpressionDSL with 
org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

import "http://www.act21.io/mamba/model/expression"
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore 

ExpressionModel:
expression=Expression;

Expression:
Comparison | Functions;
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Did you double check if the meta model plug-in is correctly packaged and added as a dependency to the mydsl plugin

Comment: The error also looks more like a problem with the classpath of the maven exec plugin

Comment: So could you share a complete reproducible (eg hello world) code base

Comment: Dependency of meta model has added to both manifest & pom.xml (under exec-maven-plugin). Sure, I will send you the code.

Comment: the problem is different. you have created a generator customization e.g. with ExpressionGeneratorModule. this one needs to be compiled before the workflow is running. therefore such classes are ususally moved to a separate plugin .eg.g my.custom.generator

Comment: I added a custom generator as I was facing the below issue -

Cannot find compatible feature variable in sealed EClass VariableRef from imported package http://www.act21.io/mamba/model/expression: The type 'EAttribute' used in the reference 'variable' is inconsistent. 

Otherwise, I do not have any requirement for a custom generator.

Comment: I added a custom generator as I was facing the below issue -

Cannot find compatible feature variable in sealed EClass VariableRef from imported package http://www.act21.io/mamba/model/expression: The type 'EAttribute' used in the reference 'variable' is inconsistent. 
Otherwise, I do not have any requirement for a custom generator.

Comment: Replacing the eType with package import solved the above problem so i removed custom generator.
eType="ecore:EClass http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EAttribute"
should be used instead of
eType="ecore:EClass platform:/resource/org.eclipse.emf.ecore/model/Ecore.ecore#//EAttribute"
in case emf ecore model needs to be referenced in the meta model.